# Autowire not working in Symfony's Dependency Injection component

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

I am using Symfony's Dependency Injection component version 3.4 in my custom PHP project. My project is running on PHP 5.6

```
"symfony/dependency-injection": "^3.4"
```

I have defined my services.yaml file to contain following service definitions

```
logger:
  class: Monolog\Logger
  arguments: ["application"]
  autowire: true
  public: true

Monolog\Logger: '@logger'

plugin_context:
  class: MyProject\PluginContext
  autowire: true
  public: true
```

I can confirm that the autoloading is working and the instance of both classes are present in the definition, but the Logger class is not autowired in PluginContext constructor. the class is defined in the following code

```
use Monolog\Logger;

class PluginContext
{
    private $logger;
    function __construct(Logger $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

When the following code is run, PHP throws an exception

```
$container->get("plugin_context");

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to MyProject\PluginContext::__construct() must be an instance of Monolog\Logger, none given
```

Comment: missing `arguments: ["Monolog\Logger"]` for `plugin_context:`? seems like your constructor require logger dependency but it is not defined in the plugin content's arguments

Comment: @Smaine's answer below about type hinting against the LoggerInterface is correct.  If you are going to use autowire then you need to have a fairly in depth understanding of how it works which means reading and understanding the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring).  And learning to use commands like "bin/console debug:container --show-private | grep logger" to see what services and aliases are available.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `FQCN $logger` and use this one `use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` instead `Monolog\Logger` 
Another thing, thanks to autowiring you don't need to specify anything in `service.yaml` except this (the default configuration):

```
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                        # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                        # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

The Doc said : « Aliases are used by the core bundles to allow services to be autowired. For example, MonologBundle creates a service whose id is logger. But it also adds an alias: Psr\Log\LoggerInterface that points to the logger service. This is why arguments type-hinted with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface can be autowired » so in your case the Psr\Log\LoggerInterface is an alias for Monolog https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring

Comment: I am using Symfony's Dependency Injection component only and my project is not based on Symfony framework. Also, why should I be using LoggerInterface instead of Monolog?

Comment: It's more easier to work with interface and many component in Symfony using the autowiring should be used with interface https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces

Comment: Thanks, I totally agree with what you said about using Interfaces but autowire should work with a Concrete classes like Monlog as well?.

Comment: Very good question I should take time to look more deeper the DependencyInjection component.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the either the contents of `services.yaml` are not full.

Your services file should be like this

```
services:
  logger:
    class: Monolog\Logger
    arguments: ["application"]
    autowire: true
    public: true

  Monolog\Logger: '@logger'

  plugin_context:
    class: MyProject\PluginContext
    autowire: true
    public: true
```